# Android Webview making long winded Jquery AJAX call

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, webview

i have a android hybrid app, where from the main activity i load the html file:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/myapp/myPage.html");
```

From this html, i load a javascript which makes a jquery ajax post call to REST API on the Dev server.  Depending on the amount of data I'm sending in the ajax call, the server can take a substantial amount of time to process the data and return a response.  When the server response is slow, i almost always get an error from the ajax call, the textStatus of which is simply "error". Smaller data calls are always successful. 
Logcat says:

```
httpFailure() ******* java.net.UnknownHostException
```

Is there some sort of timeout Android uses which may be closing the connection to the server?

Also, do ajax requests such as these run on Android's UI Thread?

I have found that the server-side processing actually completes without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a good solution to this issue.  I decided to let the asynchronous nature of a jquery ajax call just handle this situation, and not tie up the user while the app waits for the response.

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.UnknownHostException` throws when there is **No internet connection.**

Be sure your device/emulator have **internet connection** and you have give `permission` 
in `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Thanks for the answer... This is a geo-location app I'm working on so I test with an actual device, when the javascript executes the phone is using the wireless network.

Comment: But still if you are accessing internet using wireless then you need to add this permission.

Comment: Yes, agreed, and I am doing so.  The thing which is really the issue is that with a small payload the call works fine with no hitches.  It's only when sending a relatively larger amount of data to the server, and the server takes a long time to process the request that the UnknownHostException is thrown.